# start-domain failed Glassfish on Windows 7

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I wanted to start a Glassfish 4.1.1-Server on Windows 7 with JAVA 8 JDK 66, but my command asadmin start-domain failed.
This seems to be an obscure error because I get a pretty long failure message in the command prompt (see below).

Can anybody give me a hint what the problem is? Even a direction ("likly a problem with the firewall", "incompatible JDK-Version", etc.) would be a help...

Thank you
Threx

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
C:\Glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start ..........Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRunt
ime@810a64 in service registry.

    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Glassfish\glassfish
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Glassfish\glassfish\lib\te
    mplates
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Glassfish\glassfish\lib\templates\
    logging.properties
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
Nov 10, 2015 1:58:57 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvis
ioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMATION: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfis
h.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Nov 10, 2015 1:58:57 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvis
ioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 10, 2015 1:58:57 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvis
ioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNUNG: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Nov 10, 2015 1:59:01 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvis
ioner startBundles
WARNUNG: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Glassfish/glassfish/modules/core.jar beca
use it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.227+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.logging|_Thr
eadID=16;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343915;_TimeMillis=14471603
44227;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00009;|
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1  (build
 1)|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.227+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.logging|_Thr
eadID=16;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343915;_TimeMillis=14471603
44227;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00010;|
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.OD
LLogFormatter|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.461+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.
security|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160344461;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01115;|
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.
FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.477+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.
security|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160344477;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01115;|
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRea
lm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.477+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.
security|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160344477;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01115;|
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certi
ficate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.789+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.security.ser
vices|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMilli
s=1447160344789;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=SEC-SVCS-00100;|
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:04.820+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|org.hibernate.validator.inter
nal.util.Version|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343915
;_TimeMillis=1447160344820;_LevelValue=800;|
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.304+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.Ba
ckingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447
160343915;_TimeMillis=1447160345304;_LevelValue=800;|
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for per
sistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.335+0100|WARNING|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.grizzly.conf
ig.Utils|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160345335;_LevelValue=900;|
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.
server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Ht
tp2AddOn|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.428+0100|WARNING|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.grizzly.conf
ig.Utils|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160345428;_LevelValue=900;|
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.
server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Ht
tp2AddOn|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.600+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMillis=1447
160345600;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00087;|
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 172ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.600+0100|WARNING|glassfish 4.1|org.glassfish.grizzly.conf
ig.Utils|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMi
llis=1447160345600;_LevelValue=900;|
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.
server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Htt
p2AddOn|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.616+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343946;_TimeMillis=1447
160345616;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00087;|
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.662+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1447160343915;_TimeMillis=1447
160345662;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00087;|
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.662+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1447160345662;_LevelValue=800;_MessageI
D=NCLS-CORE-00017;|
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (6.974ms
), startup services(1.762ms), total(8.736ms)|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.662+0100|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.cor
e|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1447160345662;_LevelValue=1000;_Messa
geID=NCLS-CORE-00019;|
  Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChanne
lAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOB
indingHandler.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransp
ort.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransp
ort.java:237)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransp
ort.java:86)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGriz
zlyListener.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(Gl
assfishNetworkListener.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.
java:267)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.j
ava:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy
(GrizzlyService.java:567)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(Griz
zlyService.java:490)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java
:326)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:
471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate
(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelConte
xt.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl
.java:114)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl
.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.one
Job(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run
(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(
CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.740+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-11;_TimeMillis=1447160345740;_LevelValue=800;_Me
ssageID=NCLS-CORE-00092;|
  Server shutdown initiated|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:05.740+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.bootstrap|_T
hreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1447160345740;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=
NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027;|
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishIm
pl@1aa7d76 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegis
trationImpl@1a6a933.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:06.754+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.bootstrap|_T
hreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-11;_TimeMillis=1447160346754;_LevelValue=800;_Mess
ageID=NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028;|
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFish
Impl@1aa7d76 from service registry.|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:06.754+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1||_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thr
ead-8;_TimeMillis=1447160346754;_LevelValue=800;|
  FileMonitoring shutdown|#]

[#|2015-11-10T13:59:06.942+0100|INFO|glassfish 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|
_ThreadID=55;_ThreadName=Thread-11;_TimeMillis=1447160346942;_LevelValue=800;_Me
ssageID=NCLS-CORE-00013;|
  Shutdown procedure finished|#]

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support wa
s removed in 8.0

Command start-domain failed.

C:\Glassfish\bin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Glassfish cannot start because an address it is trying to bind is already in use.

> Shutting down server due to startup exception 
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Try to edit the domain.xml.

> /glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml

The most common problem would be that the http-listener ports are reused by another application.
Find the lines:

> name="http-listener-1" **port="8080"**
>   name="http-listener-1" **port="9090"**

And replace them with something like:

> name="http-listener-2" **port="8181"**
>   name="http-listener-2" **port="9191"**

You can also read more about the domain.xml

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7694/abhar/index.html

Comment: Now the problem is solved. As you guessed, the port had been occupied.
So I changend the port in the .xml-document and voilà!

Waiting for domain1 to start .......
Successfully started the domain : domain1

domain  Location: C:\Glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log File: C:\Glassfish\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.



Thank you Spyros for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, same messages (might be different cause), I solved it by moving (unzip) Glassfish folder to a different location. The problem was that when I unziped GlassFish.zip on C:\  the folder's owner was "Administrator". By unzipping it in a different location (like c:\servers\GlassFish), the owner was my regular user.
Plus I changed port="8080" and "8181" (to a 8060, 8061 in my case). My glassFish domain started successfully afterwards, I don't know which of those changes fixed it, and I don't care anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem...

1. Copy the Glassfish folder into the C:\users{your-pc-name}
2. Configure or Start cmd with C:\users{your-pc-name} by right clicking the cmd-> properties
3. Then run asadmin

It worked for me perfectly

Its important that the path in which you have started your cmd and that the glassfish folder runs in that path