# JAX-RS Rest services stopped deploying on Eclipse Glassfish

Tags: eclipse, rest, jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

I've been developing a Jersey JAX-RS application on Glassfish 4.1.1 using Eclipse for about a year now. Earlier today, I was making some normal changes to some of the classes, but Eclipse was not updating the classes when I would try and do a build. I searched here on Stack Overflow, and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573416/why-isnt-eclipse-updating-the-classes).

So I did the following steps:

1. **Project > Clean** on the project you're working on.
2. **Project > Build** Automatically - turned on so the code rebuilds in your workspace on saved changes.
3. **Window > Preferences** and make sure your Installed JRE's and Compilers are matching Java versions

My installed jre is `jdk1.8.0_73` and my compiler compliance level is 1.8

Now when I make a change to a Java file, the server tab below will still not show

> [Started, Republish]

like it should but stays at

> [Started, Synchronized].

It gets worse. Now when I try and hit the rest services using POSTMAN and queries that I've used a million times it returns a 404 saying the requested resource is not available.

So basically none of the REST services are starting properly for some reason.

If I hit the index.html for my application it gets served up fine, but when AngularJS tries to load stuff from the REST backend, it gets fed the 404 error.

I've haven't made any changes to Eclipse/Glassfish, as it was working perfectly yesterday. This is totally stopping development. Anybody know what might have gone wrong? It is extremely mind-explodingly annoying.

I'm no expert in Eclipse or Glassfish or jersey, so please go easy on me :)

Here are the build logs for when I start the server, maybe somebody can notice whats going on....

```
2016-10-02T15:24:47.575+0100|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
2016-10-02T15:24:47.576+0100|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2016-10-02T15:24:47.664+0100|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-02T15:24:47.665+0100|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-02T15:24:47.670+0100|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-02T15:24:47.775+0100|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2016-10-02T15:24:47.825+0100|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2016-10-02T15:24:47.948+0100|Info: JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
2016-10-02T15:24:47.965+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-02T15:24:48.037+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 54ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2016-10-02T15:24:48.051+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-02T15:24:48.055+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2016-10-02T15:24:48.057+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-02T15:24:48.062+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2016-10-02T15:24:48.093+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2016-10-02T15:24:48.316+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:48.655+0100|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2016-10-02T15:24:48.656+0100|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2016-10-02T15:24:48.658+0100|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2016-10-02T15:24:48.677+0100|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2016-10-02T15:24:48.829+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2016-10-02T15:24:48.833+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2016-10-02T15:24:48.835+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2016-10-02T15:24:48.849+0100|Info: Created virtual server server
2016-10-02T15:24:48.851+0100|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2016-10-02T15:24:48.995+0100|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2016-10-02T15:24:48.996+0100|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2016-10-02T15:24:49.419+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.447+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.448+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.449+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.450+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.451+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.451+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.452+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.453+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.453+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.454+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.471+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.472+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.473+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.474+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.475+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.476+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.477+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.478+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.479+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-02T15:24:49.571+0100|Info: WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)
2016-10-02T15:24:50.041+0100|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
2016-10-02T15:24:50.250+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2016-10-02T15:24:50.250+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2016-10-02T15:24:50.407+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.413+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.415+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.427+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.428+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.429+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.430+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.433+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.436+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.437+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.438+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.439+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.440+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.441+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.442+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.444+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.444+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.445+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.445+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.447+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.448+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.448+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.450+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:50.451+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-02T15:24:51.764+0100|Info: Loading application [pododdle] at [/pododdle]
2016-10-02T15:24:51.766+0100|Info: Loading application pododdle done in 3,949 ms
2016-10-02T15:24:51.766+0100|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (1,264ms), startup services(4,275ms), total(5,539ms)
2016-10-02T15:24:51.821+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2016-10-02T15:24:52.061+0100|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7bbbb6a8 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@b18c4.
2016-10-02T15:24:52.082+0100|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://PododdlePC:8686/jndi/rmi://PododdlePC:8686/jmxrmi
```

Comment: I'm still reading / digesting the entire post, but let me go ahead and ask -- do you use version control and can you use it to find the exact change in either the code or the server that caused this problem?

Comment: I think we need to take a programmatic approach to fixing this. **Step 1:** Determine if the problem is code changes using version control **Step 2:** If so, paste the code changes to this question; if not, list the other things which play a role, such as the server then start testing them one by one, like reinstalling the server.

Comment: I am using github. There was nothing out of the ordinary - just minor code changes. I was adding a DELETE for one of my resources, and maybe changing a few database queries. Thats about it.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear you say that (about Github). However minor I would encourage you to include the last diff in the question so that we can have the full picture. Having said that let me read over your log some more.

Comment: I have tried deleting the server in the servers tab, and then creating a new server but that didn't work. Also restarted my PC and eclipse but that didn't do anything.

Comment: I don't strongly suspect this to be part of the answer, but I notice that you said compliance is at 1.8. It seems like when I use facets in a project for my Tomcat server I have to turn down compliance to 1.5 even though my JDK is newer. Just a side note.  Another random thought -- since the problem is first noticable when you use AngularJS can you get anything interesting by using `console.log(whatever.calls.the.REST)` in Angular or would that just be the same generic 404 you're already seeing in the browser?

Comment: So, in your log I'm only seeing 2 general groups of warnings and no errors. Do you know if you were getting these warnings in the past before the 404?  For the first group of warnings you can find a nice list of SO questions and answers, which may or may not be relevant, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631887/start-domain-failed-glassfish-on-windows-7 . I'm seeing a lot of heterogeneous Google/SO results for the 2nd group of warnings too  mostly related to beans like  https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/300  .

Comment: I get the same stuff from angular as POSTMAN which is a tool for sending http request. In the process of reverting back a couple of commits to when it was definitely working. Haven't done this in ages, so will take me some time. There was always a few errors in the log that I haven't tracked down since things were working ok. Can't be sure they were the same as before though.

Comment: So I reverted to the old version, it worked for a while, then stopped allowing me to make changes to the java code again. When I cleaned the project, the REST services stopped working. I am now back to the most recent commit which has the problems. Weirdly, if I edit the HTML it allows me to publish the changes, but not the java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this error was caused by the project not building properly. Upon inspection of the buildpath, it seemed two jar files were mysteriously missing! They were:

```
jersey-media-multipart-2.21.1.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
```

I have no idea how the jar files were deleted from the /lib directory of the glassfish server, maybe I shouldn't have drunk that extra bottle of whiskey. Once they were added back in, everything suddenly worked hunky dory. A little baffled by the error - i would have thought it would give a compile error if the jar wasn't available. Anyhow, 5 days lost due to another annoying error.