# GlassFish server not running netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I'm not able to start my GlassFish server in netbeans to view my JSP and HTML files. I keep getting this error. I tried to delete and create the server but no point.

GlassFish Server

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[87677]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10b9314c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10d9bb4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:31 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:31 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:31 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@7a5428ab in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Users/apple/GlassFish_Server/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Users/apple/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Users/apple/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Users/apple/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/dd/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (32,095ms), startup services(741ms), total(32,836ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:180)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@629adce as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@30c0d731.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@629adce from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
```

Console:

```
ant -f /Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/MYLAB6 -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/MYLAB6 run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at /Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/MYLAB6/build/web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/MYLAB6/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)
```

The console is pointing at this line:

```
 <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [start-domain failed Glassfish on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631887/start-domain-failed-glassfish-on-windows-7)

Comment: Some other process is already bound to one of ports `8080`, `8181` or `4848`. Stop that process first and try again.

Comment: @Mike I tried to to that many times, it doesn't work

Comment: If you are getting a bind exception, it is almost certainly due to another process. GlassFish or Tomcat or something. It looks like you're on Mac, so you can use `sudo netstat -lntp` which will show you a `PID/Program name` column. Whichever PID is using a GlassFish port (the `Local Address` column), that is the one you will need to kill. If you know the PID, you can find further details about it with `ps aux | grep $PID`

Answer (score -1):

it causes due to **MaxPermSize** Java 8 removes **MaxPermSize** from configuration and take care itself. Please remove **MaxPermSize** from configuration.

Comment: This is not the answer. The `MaxPermSize` option is simply ignored by the JVM.

Comment: Hmm seem your problem is not by this cause. it says Address already in use means your glassfish instance already running behind it happens because if we directly close the console. please find the java process id and kill it first. please tell me which platform you are running the application.

Comment: @AnuragDadheech how to find the process id and kill it? I tried to search that but it doesn't work

Comment: if Windows then open task manager > process > find java related process and right click on it then select end process

Comment: if Linux then open terminal > sudo netstat -nlp > select java process id then > kill -9 "process id"